# RegularExpressionValidator expression only on submit

Tags: asp.net, .net, validation

I'm using a RegularExpressionValidator in ASP.NET on a textbox that requires 10 numbers as input.  My problem is that the error message pops up whenever I switch to a different control. For example: when I enter only 1 number and then switch to a different textbox the error message tells me that I need 10 numbers.

I would like for the REV to only validate when the submit button is pressed. I have tried to add "CauseValidation=False" to the textbox but this didn't solve the problem.

Anyone know the answer?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to avoid disabling the client script entirely (by setting `EnableClientScript="False"`). You could try handling the `change` event of the TextBox which has the validation control attached. hiding the validation message which may or may not have been displayed.

Then on sumbmit of the form the validator would still be called and displayed if necessary.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>').change(function (e) {
            var validator = $('#<%= RegularExpressionValidator1.ClientID %>');
            validator.hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can validate regular expression on server side so only when you hit submit button  RegularExpressionValidator will do validation at server and not at client side.
To do that you need to set property of validator

`EnableClientScript="False"`

Answer (score 2):

You should switch of Client Script validation for regular expression validator.

And then do on submit button event handler following:

```
Page.Validate();
if (Page.IsValid)
{
   // all ok
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Summing up the solutions:

- @f0rza's using `Page_Validate()`:

**Pros:** One-liner, you can call it at element.change() event.
**Cons:** Triggers all the validators, which is generally not wished.

- @pradmodtech's using `EnableClientScript="False"`:

**Pros:** One-liner, fits the original answer exactly.
**Cons:** Not flexible enough if you only want to ignore some of the "invalid" inputs.

- @jdavies's using `validator.hide()`:

**Pros:** A bit more of coding is required.
**Cons:** 100% flexible in more complex scenarios.

I used @jdavies's solution on an `asp:RegularExpressionValidator` with `ValidationExpression="^[0-9]{4}$"`, coupled with an `asp:RequiredValidator`, because I needed these behaviours:

- No input => no error message until validation
- 4-digit input => no error message
- less then 4 digit input => field is completed with trailing "0"s, no error message.
  [using @f0rza's solution on `blur` or on `change`, the jQuery code runs *after* the validation; this is another con of `Page_Validate()`]
- Non-numeric input => instant error message